# Password Authentication - Inconsistent Hashes

Tags: authentication, joomla, md5, joomla1.5

I am migrating from Joomla 1.5 to WordPress and my client does not want users to have to re-register. So I am writing a WordPress plugin to match a user's password with what's in the jos_users table and then update their info in WordPress accordingly.

Everything I have read so far for Joomla's password authentication points me to the getCryptedPassword function:

http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JUserHelper/getCryptedPassword

My plugin is encrypting what the user enters the same way:

```
$db_password = explode(':', $query); //what's in the password field of jos_users
$salt = $db_password[1];
$string_to_be_hashed = $user_entered_pass . $salt; 
$test_pass = md5($string_to_be_hashed);
$test_pass = $test_pass . ":" . $salt;
if($test_pass = query){echo "success"}
```

I have tested 3 accounts using this...but only 2 are authenticating.

Specifically: md5($password$salt):$salt != database password value

In the database, the password value for the account it is not working for appears to have used the same encryption and in the same format ([md5hash]:salt). I know the password is correct because I can login into the client's site with it.

In addition, I ran a search on the entire Joomla codebase for the getCryptedPassword function. In all cases, no explicit encryption method is sent - both the code and the documentation indicate that md5 is used by default.

Can anyone think of any places I should look for alternative encryption possibilities?

I have no idea where else to look or why this particular user account appears to be encrypting differently.

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla Standards The encryption handles like as follow.

```
     jimport('joomla.user.helper');
     $salt = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
     $crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword($password_choose, $salt);
     $password = $crypt.':'.$salt;
```

You can run the compare thing in a separate file by loading entire joomla framework to a single file in root.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

Also you cannot decrypt the Joomla password.If you know the password (original text) Then try with wordpress password fromat .

Hope this may helps..